# Timeout error when running e2e test in angular cli projet

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angular-cli, e2e-testing

I started working with e2e test with protractor and jasmine in angular cli project

```
describe('my-web-client App', function() {
  let page: myWebClientPage;

  beforeEach((done) => {
    page = new myWebClientPage();
  });

  it('should show menubar', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect( page.getAppMenubar().isPresent() ).toEqual(true); // getAppMenubar() return element(by.css('app-menubar'));
  });
});
```

But even with a simple test I received the following errors
[image]

Comment: Please show the `myWebClientPage` definition as well.

Comment: it still a simple class

``
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

export class myWebClientPage {
  
  navigateTo(to:string = '') {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    return browser.get('/'+to);
  }

  getAppMenubar() {
    return element(by.css('app-menubar'));
  }

  getMapElements() {
    return element(by.css('.map'));
  }
}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the `done` callback but never execute it and, according to jasmine documentation:

> ... spec will not start until the `done` function is called in the call
>   to `beforeEach` above. And this spec will not complete until its `done` is
>   called.

You can just omit it:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  page = new myWebClientPage();
});
```